# Convolution of N-dimensional surface with vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, signal-processing, convolution

I am trying to do a 'convolution' of an arbitrary N-dimensional surface with a vector. More specifically, I am trying to get the output of an N-th order Volterra kernel (see http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Volterra_and_Wiener_series, eq.1)

Thus, for a 1-dimensional kernel, the output is the simple sliding convolution of the 1st order kernel with the past input epoch. It essentially multiplies/weights every value in the past input epoch with a coefficient.

The 2nd order kernel output is a 'convolution' of a 2d matrix with a signal. This kernel weighs the product of every pair of points in the past with a coefficient.

The 3rd order kernel, a 3d matrix, weighs every triplet of points in the past memory epoch.

Also, I dont know the dimension/order of the kernel before hand. It is an input parameter..

I know I can probably do this very unelegantly and slowly by going through with several for loops point by point, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this very quickly and elegantly in matlab?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [`convn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) command?

Comment: I have, but Im not sure what it does. Whenever I try using it to convolve a surface with a vector, I get a surface output and not a vector output that I am looking for; Thus, I assume its not what I need...

Comment: This is super relevant to what I'm doing now, could use as much info as possible. Starting a bounty.

Comment: @SetSlapShot For an n-order convolution, do you want an n-dim result or a vector? The OP seemed to want a vector, but I don't see how a vector output would result. An n-dim output array would make more sense?

Comment: The OP wants a Volterra-style nonlinear system.  This generalizes linear convolution to generate, at each point, the (scalar) integral of the product of the input signal against each dimension of the kernel - see the page linked in the OP.  So, vector x n-dim -> vector is right, but the implicit definition is not something you can guess from the post!

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32248-fast-volterra-filtering

Comment: AKAIK, matlab is not very good at tensor products, unfortunately...you can manually do it by taking kronecker product of your vectors.

Comment: Another implementation: http://www-home.fh-konstanz.de/~mfranz/Code.html

Answer (score 0):

you can check the dimension of a variable with `ndims(array)`, and do convolutions on the needed dimensions: `conv()` or `conv2()` for one-dimension and 2-dimensions respectively. If you need to do a convolution on a higher dimension, you can reshape your variable with the `reshape` command and then use the previous commands.